# Parsing response form AWSTask, returned from lambda in iOS swift 3

Tags: json, swift, lambda, aws-lambda, json-serialization

Any suggestions in how to parse AWSTask.result into JSON object? I am invoking AWS Lambda function, which returns a JSON string

code below

```
let task = lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction("LambdaFunction", jsonObject: ["processName":processName])

 task.continue({ (task: AWSTask!) -> AWSTask<AnyObject>! in

        if (task.error != nil) {
            NSLog("Invoke Lambda returned an error : \(task.error)")
            //NSLog("Invoke Lambda returned an error : \(task.error)")

        } else {
            if (task.result != nil) {
                //NSLog("Invoke Lambda : result = \(task.result)")
                var data = task.result as! NSDictionary 

                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) //THIS WONT WORK, throws error that it cant cast to NSDictionary

                print("responseJSON = \(responseJSON)")



            } else {
                NSLog("Invoke Lambda : unknow result : \(task)");
                NSLog("Exception : \(task.exception)")
                NSLog("Error : \(task.error)" )
                }
        }
        return nil
```

Any recommendations to parse this to a JSON object so that I can extract specific attributes of the response/result?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? The below answer by paper1111 didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast to `NSDictionary` **after** serializing the data, not before.

```
var data = task.result

let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: When I do this, I am getting a `Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: SampleResponse?, options: [Any])'` error, where SampleResponse is the Gateway generated class in sdk.

Comment: @Rao without showing the class `SampleResponse`, it will be hard to solve your problem. Your problem should be different from this OP.

Answer (score 0):

I used SwiftyJSON for the parsing: 
Install it using cocoa pods - https://cocoapods.org

import it in your class where you want to parse

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

replace the value of resonseJSON with:

```
let responseJSON = JSON(task.result)
```